# How do i create a file variable?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a file reader variable?

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Is this right?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

You are right! you need to create like this!